# regex to find a line that has a word without another word

Tags: regex, search, include, notepad++

I have the following lines

```
test
words
more words test
&test
words and test
```

I am using Notepad++, and I want a regex to find the lines that has the word "test", if it doesn't have the symbol "&" in that line..  so in the upper example it should find lines 1, 3, 5 - but not line 4 which had "&" in the line.

I tried

```
[&]test[^\&]‎
```

and

```
^(?=.*test)(?!.*(?:&))
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
^(?!.*&).*\btest\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gI8gI3/d)

`(?!.*&)` will make sure that line doesn't have `&` in it. Make sure to use `MULTILINE` mode.

Comment: thanks, I tried in np++ but it found only the last line.

Comment: You can check my demo where it finds 3 lines. In NP++ regex tool make sure `DOTALL` is not checked otherwise only last line is matched.

Comment: @Mike this regex works. Make sure the cursor is at the beggining of the document, or click on *Find All In Current Document*. By `DOTALL`, it means to leave `". matches newlines"` unchecked.

Comment: Thanks @Mariano, I am on OSX so don't have NP++ i front of me to name the right option for unchecking `DOTALL` equivalent. Yes it indeed means that DOT must not match newlines.

Comment: @anubhava I thought so, and you're not missing much. (For the record, `/m` is on by default).

Answer (score 1):

**Find what:**

```
^[^&\n]*test[^&\n]*$
```

Uses a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to allow any characters except `&` and newlines.‎

Comment: Thanks Mariano, it works too..  I accepted the first answer, and marked your answer as useful.